# simple past or simple present

Tags: tense

> The case was approved by the employer on 03.5.2014.

or

> The case is approved by the employer on 03.5.2014.

Which tense is better while preparing a report? 
Simple present sounds better to me, but I can't be sure since "the approval" was received in the past.

Comment: I would look for a better reason than "sounds better". It is in the past, right?

Comment: Need some context to answer this question. Especially: what kind of report, for who, for what purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The present simple tense is used for past events mostly in the context of talking about history and historical facts:

> William Shakespeare is an English writer. He *starts* his writing career at the age of 10, and *continues* writing plays and poems until his death.

It can also be used when reviewing a sequence of actions, such as when considering evidence during court proceedings:

> The suspect *enters* the building at 4:15pm, *checks* to see where the security cameras are, and then *robs* the plaintiff at gunpoint.

In your example, it looks like you were given a simple acknowledgement that something happened. In that case, the past simple tense is the better choice.